# Split MAC Address and increment using Ansible

Tags: math, split, ansible, mac-address

I am trying to take a mac address and increment one of the values by 1 e.g. 46:7f:d3:17:06:0b to 46:7f:d3:17:07:0b

I have tried a couple of options to try and split the variable on : and then try to increment the value by 1 but I am still having issues.

Has anyone ever done this or something similar where you split a string, increment by 1 and then rebuild the string

UPDATE:

This is what i attempted, it increments the 06 to 7 since i am converting it to an integer so i would then need to add the 0 back before the 7.

I just wasn't sure if there was a cleaner and easier way to accomplish this.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    last_mac: "{{ vm.ovirt_nics | json_query(jmesquery)| last}}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[*].mac.address"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ last_mac }}"

- set_fact:
   value_to_increment: "{{ last_mac.split(':')[4] }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ value_to_increment }}"

- set_fact:
   incremented_value: "{{ value_to_increment | int + 1 }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ incremented_value }}"
```

Comment: `I have tried a couple of options to try and split the variable on : and then try to increment the value by 1 but I am still having issues.` => Where is the code you wrote ? What are the issues you are having ?

Comment: @Zeitounator I have just updated the post, I forgot to include that when i raised the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        incremented_value: "{{ new|join(':') }}"
      vars:
        arr: "{{ last_mac.split(':') }}"
        ar4: "{{ '%02x' % (arr.4|int(base=16) + 1) }}"
        new: "{{ arr[:4] + [ar4] + arr[5:] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  incremented_value: 46:7f:d3:17:07:0b
```

Comment: Thanks thats great, one question what does this do?

ar4: "{{ '%02x' % (arr.4|int(base=16) + 1) }}"

Comment: You are welcome. See [format](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.format).