# Increment MAC address in ansible

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I have a mac address with me. Let's suppose

```
00:ae:cd:09:db:4f
```

I need to create a loop in which each time this mac address is incremented by value 1. Let's say the loop will be iterated 2 times.

Expected output:

```
00:ae:cd:09:db:50
00:ae:cd:09:db:51
```

I need to create a list of the output.

I tried ipmath(1), tried converting to different format using hwdaddr() and other lib. But did not got any luck. Please help !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split MAC Address and increment using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67870109/split-mac-address-and-increment-using-ansible), this is quite like the same idea except that you do have to target `arr.5` to increment it.

Comment: How to do that in every iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *with_sequence*. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    mac: 00:ae:cd:09:db:4f
    count: 2
    macs: []

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        macs: "{{ macs + [new|join(':')] }}"
      with_sequence: count="{{ count }}"
      vars:
        arr: "{{ mac.split(':') }}"
        ar5: "{{ '%02x' % (arr.5|int(base=16) + item|int) }}"
        new: "{{ arr[:5] + [ar5] }}"

    - debug:
        var: macs
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  macs:
  - 00:ae:cd:09:db:50
  - 00:ae:cd:09:db:51
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir Botka. Just a doubt, how will we check the overflow while adding 1 everytime.

Comment: Right. In this case, a Python custom filter might be the best option.